# How do I prevent the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox from changing?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox, custom-controls

I am looking for an event where I can prevent the SelecteIndex property of a ComboBox from being set.
Maybe also a self created event named "SelectedIndexChanging".
I need this to stop the SelectedIndex from changing until a specific condition is true.

I tried looking for an Event where i can prevent the change of SelectedIndex.
Also I tried in my CustomComboBox to implement an Event to stop this.
No success here.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
When the Usere change the ComboBox, i will look if that object is saved in database and when not, if will mask him(With a MessageBox) if he wanted to save. With that DialogResult, i want to interrupt the changing of the SelectedIndex.

Comment: I would think either disabling the control or filtering all but the current item from the drop-down list would be the way to go. I'm not aware of any way to prevent a change in selection. Maybe even don't display the `ComboBox` at all if you don't want the selection changed and use a read-only `TextBox` instead., if you're against disabling the control.

Comment: I am against disabeling the ComboBox also it is not possible to use a TextBox

Comment: You really need to add more details, to better define this *requirement*. Avoid changing the current selection in which case? When a User selects an Items from the interface? When bound to a source of data, no User interaction (only handling the Currency Manager)? Other (e.g., disabling items that cannot be selected in some context -> see [Disabling a ComboBox Item based on a CheckBox state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56992518/7444103) <- no need to draw the items *disabled*)?

Comment: Why not just set `ComboBox.Enabled = false;` until the user is allowed to change it, and then set it to `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit of a hack, because the `SelectedIndex` property value does actually change but is changed back again if the `SelectedIndexChanging` event is cancelled, but it will certainly appear to work from the user's perspective. You might need to check how things like `SelectedValue` behave, if you're using them.

```cs
internal class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    private int previousSelectedIndex = -1;
    private bool isRevertingSelectedIndex = false;

    public event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> SelectedIndexChanging;

    protected virtual void OnSelectedIndexChanging(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedIndexChanging?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isRevertingSelectedIndex)
        {
            isRevertingSelectedIndex = false;

            // Ignore the event altogether.
            return;
        }

        var cea = new CancelEventArgs();

        OnSelectedIndexChanging(cea);

        if (cea.Cancel)
        {
            // Revert the index to its previous value, so it appears not to have changed.
            isRevertingSelectedIndex = true;
            SelectedIndex = previousSelectedIndex;

            // Do not process the event any further.
            return;
        }

        // Commit the index change.
        previousSelectedIndex = SelectedIndex;

        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    }
}
```

You just handle the `SelectedIndexChanging` event and set `e.Cancel` to `true` if the `SelectedIndex` shouldn't change.

Comment: After `isRevertingSelectedindex` is set to `true`, how is it ever reset to `false`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, missed that. Fixed.

Comment: I only tried to stop it before changing the Index. I was trapped in my thoughts. 
Thank you man, I think its a little bit "dirty" but works great.

Answer (score 0):

Another little hack...
Create a field (Tuple) where you can keep track of the last selected index and whether it can be changed or not...

```
(bool blockChanges, int atIndex) comboRestriction = (false, 0);
```

In the SelectionChanged method you add this:

```
ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;

if (comboRestriction.blockChanges && combo.SelectedIndex != comboRestriction.atIndex)
{
     combo.SelectedIndex = comboRestriction.atIndex;
     return;
}
else if (comboRestriction.blockChanges)
{
      return;
 }

// Combo Changed - track last index
comboRestriction = (false, combo.SelectedIndex);
...
```

When you want to "block" the comboBox, set this to "true":

```
comboRestriction.blockChanges = true;
```